# Indent controls using AlternationIndex

Tags: wpf, xaml

Is it possible to indent controls using the count of the itemcontrol (AlternationIndex)?

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ConditionList}" AlternationCount="{Binding ConditionList.Count}">
 </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
  </DataTemplate>
   <WrapPanel Background="#FFB1CBCB">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyText}" Name="BlankText"/>
   </WrapPanel>
   <DataTemplate.Triggers>
     <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="0">
       <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,0" TargetName="BlankText"/>
     </Trigger>
   </DataTemplate.Triggers>                                                
  </DataTemplate>
 </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

Basically I want to keep indenting the BlankText textbox using its margin as below

```
TextBox1
 TextBox2
  TextBox3
```

Is it possible to use AlternationIndex somehow to achieve this? I know my xaml will fire the trigger only on index 0 but its just to explain what I want it to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a converter that receives `AlternationIndex` and returns the correct margin for the text block.